# How to not allow inputting only the minus sign (-) but also allow signed numbers?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm making an calculator and when I input just the minus sign (-) the app crashes.
I have an editText with inputType of number and numberSigned but I also want to accept signed numbers but not just the minus sign (-)

Comment: Please share your code and stack trace for more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it programmatically by checking whether the entered value is signed integer and not just a sign(-/+) of or something unexpected values

*i.e.*
use regular expression

`^-?[0-9]\d*(\.\d+)?$`

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the crash is due to an exception thrown by some piece of code that expects a String `"-"` to parse to an integer.

What do you want to do when that exception occurs? Capture this exception with a `try` `catch` and do it in the `catch` block.